# How do I install Mono 5.18.0?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mono

I would like to install **[Mono 5.18.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.18.0/)** on Ubuntu 20.04. All I could find was an installation guide for [accessing older releases](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases) which technically breaks down to:

> If you want to pin an older version of Mono you can modify the Debian repository to
> “stable-jessie/snapshots/X.XX.X” instead of “stable-jessie”. For
> example, “stable-jessie/snapshots/3.10.0” will lock you to that
> version.

How do I do that? My `/etc/apt/sources.list/d/mono-official-stable.list` file includes the following record, `deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main`. Will it work if I edit it like this?

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu 5.18.0
```

and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-develo # or mono-complete?
```

Comment: What makes that ancient software appealing to you? A lot of legacy native dependencies no longer exist on Ubuntu 20.04, so you probably aren't able to even compile from source code. Nobody can provide you deb packages either, as they move on to latest Mono or .NET Core/.NET 5.

Comment: Found out why as you posted another thread. You misunderstood the answer there, so Mono 5.18 won't help you any way. Fight against the demand that you "must use 4.7.2". There is no .NET Framework 4.7.2 on Linux, and you have to use Windows to stick to .NET Framework 4.7.2 or migrate to .NET Core/.NET 5. All other paths just waste your time.